# Can someone explain me what i did wrong with this scroll function?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to build my first android app using kotlin, and I got a number of images and I want to track which images I scrolled over.

I put all my images in the ArrayList buttons and created a mutableListOf() activated to put all the activated images in. Because it doesn't work, I also made a var test = 0 and increase it every time onScroll() is called.

```
override fun onScroll(
        event1: MotionEvent,
        event2: MotionEvent,
        distanceX: Float,
        distanceY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        test++
        for(i in buttons){
            if (!activated.contains(i.id.toString()) && event1.x > i.left && event1.x < i.right && event1.y < i.bottom && event1.y > i.top) {
                activated.add(i.id.toString())
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, i.id.toString())
            }
        }
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onScroll: $activated $test")

        return true
    }
```

I thought this would work, but it just works the first time onSroll() is called after onDown(). It doesnt add images to activated after that. Test increases as expected, but it doesn't help me know what I did wrong. Can someone please help me?

Comment: "It doesnt add images to activated after that." --> `if (!activated.contains(i.id.toString())`

Comment: I tried deleting it and it still doesn't add new images, but it does add more dublicates depending on how long I scrolled, which I think is weird

Comment: How do you fill `buttons` collection? Post your code, please.